# How to reference a string resource of a library from inside the library

Tags: java, android

I have read [question 15557913]: ([How to reference a string in strings.xml of an Android library in code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15557913/how-to-reference-a-string-in-strings-xml-of-an-android-library-in-code)) and 
[How to reference a string from another package in a library using XML in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8262807/how-to-reference-a-string-from-another-package-in-a-library-using-xml-in-android)

but still I am confused ....
if I understand it correctly, the R of the app and the one of the library are merged, thus even if using the R in the library with the context of the app, I should get my resource....

(following the comments, i now post the original program flow ), so I have

```
UtilsApp/app -in fact a test app for the utils
        /nohutils/../src/../Command.java collection of utils e.g. this class
                 /res

NohFibu/app 
           /src with the MainActivity e.g. context...
           /res
       /jfibu/src../FibuCommand extends Command library of utils building on nohutils
             /res
```

the MainActivity:

```
package com.nohkumado.nohfibu;
import com.nohkumado.nohfibu.R;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements MsgR2StringI
{
  ....
  ShellI console = null;
  ....
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ....
    if (console == null)  console = new Shell(this);
    else console.setContext(this);
    ....

    HashMap<String,CommandI> cmds = new HashMap<String,CommandI>();
    cmds.put("1", new EditJrlCmd(console));
    cmds.put("2", new EditKplCmd(console));
    ... etc ... 

    @Override
    public String msg(int stringid)
    {
     try
     {  
        return(getResources().getString(stringid));
     }
     catch (Resources.NotFoundException e)
     { Log.e(TAG, "not found message : " + stringid);}
     return("MSGNOTFOUND");
    }
    ...
```

now i have in FibuCommand a method:

```
package com.nohkumado.jfibu.commands;
public class FibuCommand extends Command 
{
  public FibuCommand(ShellI s)
  {
    super(s);
  }// public EditJrlCmd()
  public String msg(int resourceId)
  {
    MsgR2StringI msger = (MsgR2StringI) shell.get("msger");
    return(msger.msg(resourceId));      
  }// public String msg(String m)
```

and last:

```
package com.nohkumado.nohutils;
public class Command implements CommandI 
{
  ....
  protected ShellI shell = null;
  ...
  public Command(ShellI s)
  {
    shell = s;
  }// public Command()

package com.nohkumado.nohutils;
public class Shell implements ShellI,OnEditorActionListener,OnKeyListener
{
  ....
  protected MsgR2StringI context = null;
  ....
  public Shell(MsgR2StringI c)
  {
    super();
    context = c;
    ....
  }// public Shell()
```

now when i try to invoke msg(R.string.nofibuobj); my IDE tells me an error of Unknown Member 'nofibuobj' of 'com.nohkumado.nohutils.R.string'
but if i write msg(com.nohkumado.jfibu.R.string.nofibuobj) the IDE stops complaining, but at exe time i get an ugly MSGNOTFOUND....

but the msg method is invoked in the package com.nohkumado.jfibu.commands on the context of the package com.nohkumado.nohfibu, its true that the method inherits from the class of package com.nohkumado.nohutils.

i just want a class of package com.nohkumado.jfibu (and subpackages) to access the resource in com.nohkumado.jfibu.R.string.... how to achieve that?

thanks in advance!
B

Comment: Where is `context` declared (the one you use in `msg()`) and how is it initialized?

Comment: context is a reference on MainActivity, passed down in the constructor of each FibuCommand, and in MainActivity::onCreate method i have a loop instantiating all those objects and passing them itself.

Comment: Including the declaration for `context` and the constructor for `FibuCommand` (as well as the surrounding `class` declaration) would help to make your question a little more clear.

Comment: What is the package names containing the classes involved? In particular, what packages contain `MainActivity` and `FibuCommand`? Where do you call the `FibuCommand.msg()` method?

Comment: ok, i tryed to make it more simple, but as requested, i now posted the whole flow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok,
instead of putting the msg method in FibuCommand, i put it into the MainActivity of the app, and it works.... can't say why

to shorten up the calls, i had to import explicitely the R of the library project, even if the documentation says i shouldn't, but its the only way to get rid of the fully qualified naming...

Answer (score 0):

The "problem" is that `MainActivity` and `FibuCommand` are in different Java packages. I suggest you learn about packages and the `import` statement.

Note that there is also another class named `R`. This is usually in the same package as `MainActivity`. The exact package name is declared in `AndroidManifest.xml` as the `package` attribute in the `<application>` tag or in `build.gradle` as the `applicationId` in `defaultConfig`. Whenever you create classes in different packages than this root package, you must have an `import` statement for `R`. This is actually no different than using any other class from a different package.